# Output "build complete" when TypeScript compiler is done?

Tags: typescript

I'm using the -w flag of the TypeScript compiler to "watch" my TypeScript files.  This is a handy feature as it will automatically recompile any files that I make a change to, on the fly.

However, because there is no "build complete" message, I have to infer that the build is complete by seeing that the output seems to have stopped.

Is there a way to get the compiler to output a "build complete" message?

Comment: Curious as to the version you are using...I do not see -w as an option in 0.9.0.1

Comment: I have never seen it either!

Comment: I'm using 0.9.0.1.  Just type execute tsc and you should see this as the second to last option: `-w, --watch                 Watch input files`

Comment: BASarat...it's well documented that you must use node version of tsc:
node "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\tsc.js" @tscbuild.txt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I accomplished this by putting this on line 24819 of tsc.js:

```
        _this.compile();
        _this.ioHost.printLine("Build Complete (" + new Date() + "): ");
```

I found this by looking for the string "Recompiling" in the source.

I was hoping to find a switch or option that could accomplish this, but this works for now.  This is inside the `onWatchedFileChange` function so presumably you will only get the notification on the 2nd and subsequent builds, not on the first build.

Comment: Awesome!! Thanks! Although the line number was different in my case, but finding the '_this.compile()' and adding code after was not that difficult.